# Polymorphism OOP : Instance of 'child' has no 'basic_attack' memberpylint (no-member)

Tags: oop, polymorphism

I'm trying to understand Polymorphism in OOP, i've built a monster parent class, from this main class you can inherit oarcs, wizards and giants..but the main attack method is coded in the parent monster class, and have only a string that is put in a variable name *basic_attack*

The problem is when i call this attack variable in oarcs, wizards or giants in the child classes, i get this error *Instance of 'oarc' has no 'basic_attack' memberpylint(no-member)*

please go easy on me and feel free to review my code below.

```
class monster:
    def __init__(self, damage, speed, skill):
        self.damage = damage
        self.speed = speed
        self.skill = skill 

    def attack(self):
        basic_attack = "you've been attacked by "
        return basic_attack

class oarc(monster):
    def __init__(self, damage, speed, skill, oarc_data):
        super().__init__(damage, speed, skill)
        self.oarc_data = oarc_data

    def attack(self):
        return self.basic_attack + self.oarc_data

class wizard(monster):
    def __init__(self, damage, speed, skill, wizard_data):
        super().__init__(damage, speed, skill)
        self.wizard_data = wizard_data

    def attack(self):
        return self.basic_attack + self.wizard_data

class giant(monster):
    def __init__(self, damage, speed, skill, giant_data):
        super().__init__(damage, speed, skill)
        self.giant_data = giant_data

    def attack(self):
        return self.basic_attack + self.giant_data

oarc_object = oarc(56, 150, 'ugly', 'Oarc')
wizard_object = wizard(20, 100, 'fast', 'Wizard')
giant_object = giant(100, 20, 'strong', 'Giant')

list = [oarc_object, wizard_object, giant_object]

for each in list:
    print(each.attack)

print(oarc_object.attack())
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, basically looks like `self.basic_attack` is never set. Could probably fix with `self.basic_attack = basic_attack` in `def __init__()` of `class Monster`.

The `basic_attack = "you've been attacked by "` under `def attack()` in `class Monster` is not the same as setting `basic_attack`. That `basic_attack` is constrained to the `attack()` function.

For example, let's abstract at non-OOP code;

```
# define a 
a = 0

def test():
  # define out
  a = 2
  # output out
  return a

print(test())
>> 2 

print(a)
>> 0
```

Now, if we did not redefine `a` in `test()`:

```
# set a
a = 0

# define test
def test():
  return a

print(test())
>> 0

print(a)
>> 0
```

Now if `a` was only defined within `test()`;

```
# define test
def test():
  # set a
  a = 2
  # output
  return a

print(test())
>> 2

print(a)
>> NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

Here's a short Intro to OOP in Python;
[Quick & easy; Object-oriented Programming from the ground up with Examples from Pikachu and Bay Area Rapid Transit (BART)](https://medium.com/future-vision/intro-to-oop-with-python-39ba63967e45)

And here's a bit more in-depth application of OOP to post to LinkedIn;
[LinkedOut](https://medium.com/future-vision/linkedout-368419e57fd7)